# How can I avoid overlapping when creating sprites? JS - PHASER3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm new in this and I'm making a small game in JS, the problem that I have now is when I create enemies it sometimes overlaps, creating this:

[image]

The way that use to create them is simple,

```
resetShip(enemy_spaceship) {
    enemy_spaceship.y = 0;
    enemy_spaceship.x = Phaser.Math.Between(10,globalThis.config.width);
}
```

In X each sprite will have a random number from 10 to the width of the screen (canvas), the problem is that if a sprite has 440 in X and another one has 450 in X, those 10px aren't enough to separate them, some people told me to create a grid, but like I said I'm new and searching about grid can't find any example that I can use to this, thanks if you can help me :)

Comment: Are you trying to avoid collisions between them during updates, or are you trying to ensure they are not placed in overlapping positions initially?

Comment: If it is during initial create, are you trying to create N different ships, each such that they won't overlap?

Answer (score 0):

One option is for each enemy ship to be allocated a specific region in which it may start. If you have 2 ships, that means the first ship can be anywhere in the first half of the X axis, and the second ship can be anywhere in the second half of the X axis.

To do this, you should update your `resetShip` function to also take in a `minX` and `maxX`, and use that when defining it's location:

```
resetShip (enemy_spaceship, minX, maxX) {
  enemy_spaceship.y = 0;
  enemy_spaceship.x = Phaser.Math.Between(minX, maxX);
}
```

Then, you need to find a way to rest the group of ships, providing valid regions for each ship. Something like this:

```
resetEnemies(ships) {
  //Each ship may be in a region that is 1/Nth of the width 
  let regionWidth = globalThis.config.width / ships.length
  //We need to know the shipWidth so we don't let ships get too
  //close to the left edge.
  let shipWidth = 64 

  ships.forEach((ship, i) => {
    //Assuming you just want padding on the left so it is no closer than 10px, 
    //this will define the minX for the Nth ship
    const minX = Math.min(10, i*regionWidth)
    //The maxX should not let a ship overlap the next region. So, we subtract the shipWidth
    //to ensure that, at worst, it is right next to the next ship
    const maxX = (i+1)*regionWidth-shipWidth

    //Use the updated restShip to put it in a valid location for it's region
    resetShip(ship, minX, maxX)
  })
}
```